# Understanding MySQLs behaviour when adding a autoincremented primary key afterwards

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

Let's say we have a (InnoDB) table `associations` in a MySQL-Database which has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `associations` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_id_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_id_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_id_3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `some_unique_constraint` (`fk_id_1`,`fk_id_2`),
  KEY `fk_id_2_INDEX` (`fk_id_2`),
  KEY `fk_id_3_INDEX` (`fk_id_3`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin$$
```

There are *jumps* in the column `id` (I know this is an issue of how the autoincremented value is generated while multiple threads try to get one). Since no other table is using the column `id` as a reference I plan to drop the column `id` and to create it again, hopefully the counting holes will be gone. I backed up my database and tested that. The result was a little confusing. The order of the rows seemed to have changed. If I am not mistaken the order is first by `fk_id_1` then `fk_id_2` then `fk_id_3`.

Is this the natural order in which MySQL sets the table, when assignung an new generated autoincrement key to the rows?

Is there more I should know, that happened during this process?

The reason, why I need to know about this is that I need to make the column `id` useful for another task I intend to accomplish where gaps are a no go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no natural order to a table in any mainstream RDBS.

Only the outermost ORDER BY in a SELECT statement will guarantee the order of results.

If you want "order":

- create a new table
- INSERT..SELECT..ORDER BY fk_id_1, fk_id_2, fk_id_3
- Drop old table
- Rename new table

Or live with gaps... OCD isn't good for developers

Edit:

Question says "no dependency" on this value but turns out there is.

If gaps are not allowed then don't use autonumber and use fk_id_1, fk_id_2, fk_id_3 as your key, with a ROW_NUMBER emulation. Or code your downstream to deal with gaps.

Autonumbers will have gaps: immutable fact of life.

Comment: I need to make this column useful for another task I intend to accomplish where gaps are a no go. Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: I googled `ROW_NUMBER` emulation and the results were confusing. So just to be sure: Do you mean to just identify the rows by an additional column which contains all three indexes of all three columns? If yes, what do you mean by `ROW_NUMBER` emulation?

Comment: @Aufwind: Other RDBMS have ROW_NUMBER() OVER () to generate sequential numbers eg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx MySQL doesn't but can be worked around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql It depends if the sequential numbers need to be the same from call to call. If not, use ROW_NUMBER replacement. If yes, then you can't do it with Autonumber. FYI: autonumber/identity values should have no intrinsic meaning anyway. They are simply internal surrogate keys